# ROS2: Adding parameters to YAML launch file

Tags: ros2, launch-file

How do I use a YAML launch file to pass parameters to a node? The tutorial covers passing parameters using a python launch file but not YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working example [here](https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_launch_examples/blob/rolling/launch/yaml_param_passing.launch.yaml).

In `dz_launch_examples/launch/yaml_param_passing.launch.yaml` I have launch file contents:

```yaml
launch:
- node:
    pkg: "turtlesim"
    exec: "turtlesim_node"
    name: "sim"
    namespace: "turtlesim_dz"
    param:
      -
        from: $(find-pkg-share dz_launch_examples)/config/turtlesim_custom_params.yaml
```

and I have a parameter file `dz_launch_examples/config/turtlesim_custom_params.yaml` with the contents:

```
/turtlesim_dz/sim:
  ros__parameters:
    background_b: 0
    background_g: 204
    background_r: 255
    use_sim_time: false
```

This runs a turtlesim node with an orange background color.

I've found that the [migration guide from ROS 1 to ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Migrating-from-ROS1/Migrating-Launch-Files.html) can be helpful in discovering how to do things in ROS 2 launch.

In working out some of the launch examples [here](https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_launch_examples/), I've observed that YAML syntax closely mirrors XML examples, even if that results in (in my opinion) a non-obvious syntax for the YAML.

In XML, passing parameters from file in ROS 2 is described [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Migrating-from-ROS1/Migrating-Launch-Files.html#rosparam). It uses the `from` attribute in a `<param>` tag:

```xml
<node pkg="my_package" exec="my_executable" name="my_node" ns="/an_absolute_ns">
   <param from="/path/to/file"/>
</node>
```

In YAML this becomes:

```yaml
- node:
    pkg: "my_package"
    exec: "my_executable"
    name: "my_node"
    namespace: "/an_absolute_ns"
    param:
      -
        from: "/path/to/file"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, what if I wanted to just load the parameters from the launch file vs a separate config file?

Comment: That case is covered in the Python/XML/YAML examples here:

https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html?highlight=yaml%20launch